# Jquery UI Slider next/previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

How i can get next or previous value from slider? I have slider with minimal allowed value: **0**, maximum allowed value: **95**, step: **3** and default value is: **10**

```
$('#myslider').slider( "option", "min", 0 );
$('#myslider').slider( "option", "max", 95 );
$('#myslider').slider( "option", "step", 3 );
$('#myslider').slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

How i can triggering to set or get next value. If my value is 30 next value will be **33**, previous value will be **27**

Comment: What happens if you output this: `$("#myslider").slider("value"));`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can grab the current value using `$("#myslider").slider("value");` I think you could find the previous and next values using the following:

```
var curr = $("#myslider").slider("value");
var step = $("#myslider").slider("option", "step");
var next = $("#myslider").slider("value", curr + step);
var prev = $("#myslider").slider("value", curr - step);
```

Comment: if this plugin doesn't have this methods need to do handwrite code, problem i have a lot of sliders with different parameters i need a lot handwrite because need check exceed maximum or minimum..

Comment: @Tom I'm not entirely sure on what you're asking. Could you clarify your comment for me?